# Best algorithm to compare two lists in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists (list1 and list2) in python filled with an own datatype. 
I want to compare these to lists and give all elements of these lists to stdout(or somewhere else), but in a specific order(without sorting the lists in any way).

List1 and List2 can have elements which are not in the other list, but can also have elements which be in the other list. These elements, beeing in both lists, should output at the same line. But the elements beeing only in one list, should be in the right order too, at the end.

Example:

```
List1 = [A,B,C,D,F,H,G];
List2 = [A,C,D,E,H];

output should be:

List1 |List2
  A      A
  B      
  C      C
  D      D
         E
  F
  H      H
  G
```

How can I "sort" in these way?

Comment: As a counter question, how can you print a list in sorted order without sorting it?

Comment: so it's not really sorted. Sorting means, for me, I can change the order of the elements within the list, but this I don't want to do(or: I must not do). This is a example of the output ;)

Comment: But you did change the order of elements in the example.

Comment: edited, this was a mistake of myself

Comment: Use `difflib` to compare.

Comment: I'm still uncertain what the desired behavior is. What should happen if the input is: List1 = [A,B,C,H,G,D,F,]; List2 = [C,D,E,H,A]; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import difflib, re

list_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'G']
list_b = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H']

for i in difflib.Differ().compare(list_a, list_b):
    differ_char, letter = re.match(r'([\s\-+]) ([A-Z])', i).groups()
    choices = ['  ' + letter, letter + '  ', letter + ' ' + letter]
    print choices[['+', '-', ' '].index(differ_char)] # print lines
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw it thanks. But I'll be changing it soon.

Comment: Its k , then reject my change and change it by yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` instead of `difflib.Differ` if you want to align something else than strings.

```py
import difflib
def align(a, b):
    return sum((zip(a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]) if tag == 'equal' 
                  else map(None, a[i1:i2], []) + map(None, [], b[j1:j2])
                        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 
                        in difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_opcodes()), [])
```

Example with integers:

```
list_a = [1, 2,    4, 5,    7]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4,    6, 7]

for (a,b) in align(list_a, list_b):
    print '{0:^5}|{1:^5}'.format(a or '',b or '')
```

Results:

```
  1  |  1  
  2  |  2  
     |  3  
  4  |  4  
  5  |     
     |  6  
  7  |  7
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to do this.

```
List1 = ['A','B','C','D','F','H','G']
List2 = ['A','C','D','E','H']

List3 = set(List1 + List2)
for i in sorted(List3, key=lambda item: item):
    if i in List1 and i in List2:
            print('{0} | {0}'.format(i))
    elif i in List1:
        print('{0} | '.format(i))
    elif i in List2:
        print('  | {0}'.format(i))

A | A
B | 
C | C
D | D
  | E
F | 
G | 
H | H
```

Comment: Your key function is entirely unnecessary.  `sorted` would produce *exactly* the same output without it.  Also, your testing of membership inside a for loop delivers quadratic performance.  Not good.

Comment: It just for result in alphabet order.

Comment: Let me make this clear:  `sorted(List3, key=lambda item: item) == sorted(List3)` evaluates to `True`.  But that's not the reason for my downvote.  The downvote is for the unnecessarily inefficient algorithm.