# Sorting a list and adding None values in the right positions

Tags: python, list

This is somehow related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675480/best-algorithm-to-compare-two-lists-in-python).

I have to lists of URLs. 
The first list is:

```
http://example.com/1/1.jpg
http://example.com/2/2.jpg
http://example.com/3/3.jpg
...
http://example.com/45000/45000.jpg
```

The second list is a subset of the first one: its made of *real* URLs, the ones that are *not* broken links.

```
http://example.com/12/12.jpg
http://example.com/23/23.jpg
http://example.com/34/34.jpg
...
```

I would like to know how to sort it in a way where I can have something like this

```
...
None
http://example.com/12/12.jpg
None
None
...
None
http://example.com/23/23.jpg
None
...
```

The point is to have a sorted list where I can have the real URLs at the right position in the final csv file.

I've tried this reading the first list and try to match with the item in the second list, but I'm failing in using both the double loop and the matching pattern.

I read the lists from files, using `open()`: this means I have to deal with line breaks (it seems to be a issue).

Comment: Please help me write a decent title for the question (and tags too).

Comment: How is getting `None` is the correct spot useful? What are doing with this listing of URLs after "sorting"?

Comment: No elements from the "real URL" list appear in the "total URL" list. What exactly do you mean by "subset"?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It is useful for my final csv, as I can copy and paste the list in my column and, at the end of the polishing of the whole file, delete all the "None" with a simple search&replace. Make sense?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My examples are misleading. I have a "total URLs" list that goes from 1 to 45000. I have a "real URLs" list that is about 11'000 elements, kinda random. That is what I mean as "subset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you first list (superset) is l1 and second (subset) is l2.

```
l3 = []
for li in l1:
    if li in l2:
        l3.append(li)
    else:
        l3.append(None)
```

This will do. I am really not an expert in python so there might be better ways, but this is what I will use.

### Update

As per your comment. Let us say you have two files. superset.txt (with all urls) and subset.txt (with some urls).

superset.txt

```
http://example.com/1/1.jpg
http://example.com/2/2.jpg
http://example.com/12/12.jpg
http://example.com/3/3.jpg
http://example.com/23/23.jpg
http://example.com/3/3.jpg
http://example.com/34/34.jpg
http://example.com/45000/45000.jpg
```

subset.txt

```
http://example.com/12/12.jpg
http://example.com/23/23.jpg
http://example.com/34/34.jpg
```

Below script will read them (from the same folder) and create the required list.

```
f1 = open("superset.txt","r")
f2 = open("subset.txt","r")
l1 = list(f1)
l2 = list(f2)
l3 = []
for li in l1:
    if li in l2:
        l3.append(li.strip())
    else:
        l3.append(None)

print l3     # or you can save this to a file.
```

Result

```
[None, None, 'http://example.com/12/12.jpg', None, 'http://example.com/23/23.jpg', None, None, None]
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because my lists are files, and I need to open them. The list of URLs thus breaks the line after every URL. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: So one file with list of all urls and second with one some urls. you need another file that will result in the resultant list? If that is correct, I can update my code to do that??

Comment: yes. I think I have a problem with line breaks, that is why is not matching the URLs.

Comment: I think I made the dumbest of mistakes... I used .split() instead of .strip()! :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple list-comp along with ternary condition like this

```
>>> orig = ['http://example.com/1/1.jpg','http://example.com/2/2.jpg','http://example.com/3/3.jpg']
>>> real = ['http://example.com/1/1.jpg']
>>> [i if i in real else None for i in orig]
['http://example.com/1/1.jpg', None, None]
```

It would be better if the `real` list is stored into a set as the processing will be faster. In that case, the code would be

```
>>> orig = ['http://example.com/1/1.jpg','http://example.com/2/2.jpg','http://example.com/3/3.jpg']
>>> real = ['http://example.com/1/1.jpg']
>>> real_set = set(real)
>>> [i if i in real_set else None for i in orig]
[u'http://example.com/1/1.jpg', None, None]
```

<sub>Thanks to mata and Cuadue for the second version using sets. Check their comments below.</sub>

Comment: it would probably be more efficient to convert `real` to a set first

Comment: The comp should be `real_set = set(real); [i if i in real_set else None for i in orig]` to get O(n) vs O(n**2)

Comment: @BhargavRao - the order only depends on the order of `orig`, using a set for the `in` check doesn't change that.

Comment: The ordering is retained by iterating over `orig`, so I think it's a win-win.

Comment: @bhargav-rao this actually worked. My initial issue is that I read the list from a file, and so every URL ends with an "\n", which has always broken the matching procedure.

Comment: @Aubrey glad to have helped you!  I hadn't seen your edit before (as I was studying for exam I was a bit busy). Apologies for not mentioning the procedure to strip the new lines. I'll enhance my answer once my exam gets over today. Thanks anyway.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
output_list = [i if i in list2 else None for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
list1 = ['http://example.com/1/1.jpg','http://example.com/2/2.jpg','http://example.com/3/3.jpg']
list2 = ['http://example.com/5/11.jpg','http://example.com/20/20.jpg','http://example.com/9/9.jpg','http://example.com/12/12.jpg']


length_of_list = max(set([int(i) for i in ''.join(list1+list2).split('/') if i.isdigit()]))

final_list = [None]*length_of_list 

for i in list1+list2:
    position = [int(x) for x in [s for s in i.split("/")] if x.isdigit()][0]
    final_list[position-1] = i

for x in final_list:
    print x

>> 
http://example.com/1/1.jpg
http://example.com/2/2.jpg
http://example.com/3/3.jpg
None
http://example.com/5/11.jpg
None
None
None
http://example.com/9/9.jpg
None
None
http://example.com/12/12.jpg
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
http://example.com/20/20.jpg
```